# Prototype object Date inheritance not working

Tags: javascript, date, inheritance, prototype

Considering this works.

**Prototype:**

```
function A(color){
 this.color = color
}

A.prototype.test = function(){
 return this.color
}
```

**Inheritance:**

```
function B(){
 A.call(this)
}

B.prototype = Object.create(A.prototype)
B.prototype.constructor = B

B.prototype.test2 = function(){
 return 'whatever...'
}
```

**Instance:**

```
const inst = new B(black)
console.log(inst.test()) //black
console.log(inst.test2()) //whatever...
```

Because this doesn't work.

**Date object inheritance:**

```
function A(){
 Date.call(this)
}

A.prototype = Object.create(Date.prototype)
A.prototype.constructor = A

A.prototype.test = function(){
 return 'whatever...'
}
```

**Instance:**

```
console.log(new A().getDay()) //Uncaught TypeError: this is not a Date object.
console.log(new A().test()) //whatever...
```

I tried inheriting with class syntax and it works perfect but not what I want

**Date object inheritance with class:**

```
class A extends Date {
 constructor(){
  super()
 }
 test(){
  return 'whatever...'
 }
}
```

**Instance:**

```
console.log(new A().getDay()) //3
console.log(new A().test()) //whatever...
```

It works perfect, but I don't want to use the class syntax.

Comment: "*Considering this works*", no it doesn't, it throws a reference error because *color* is not defined.

Comment: The methods of *Date.prototype* **only** work on instances of Date per [*ECMA-262*](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-properties-of-the-date-prototype-object): "*Unless explicitly defined otherwise, the methods of the Date prototype object defined below are not generic and the this value passed to them must be an object that has a [[DateValue]] internal slot that has been initialized to a time value.*" You can't turn a plain object into a Date object simply by assigning *Date.prototype* to its internal *[[prototype]]*.

Comment: Oh, and calling the Date constructor as a function simply returns a string representing the current date and time as for `new Date().toString()`, so `Date.call(this)` does nothing to modify the value passed as *this*, and `new A()` just returns an instance of *A*.

Comment: I had forgotten to change "porp" to "color", now it is edited. Would you have any idea how to make it work? If it works with the class syntax it should also work the other way.

Comment: `function A(...args) {`
    `return Reflect.construct(Date, args, new.target)`
 `}`

 `A.prototype.diff = function() {`
    `return alert(this.getTime());`
 `};`
   
 `Reflect.setPrototypeOf(A.prototype, Date.prototype)`

Comment: I managed to make it work that way, but it doesn't convince me either, since if I want to add an attribute in the constructor it doesn't work.

Comment: 2 years later the same thing happened to me again and I couldn't find a solution, it's in the documentation [Link to the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new.target)